# How to setup NT Challenge on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, authentication, deployment

I want to setup NT Challenge for a web application. I have read a lot of articles but still not clear how can I setup it on windows server R2. Could anyone please point me settings/Configurations to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Authentication?

Comment: @MDMarra: Correct

Answer (score 2):

In the IIS management console, remove Anonymous Access for the site in question and enable Windows Authentication. Then, use NTFS permissions on the folders/files that make up the site. This will determine what the user has access to after they are challenged.